# Any tool like TCPMon for linux to edit message on the go

Tags: http, packet-sniffers, tcpmon

I have a server and a client exchanging HTTP messages, I want a tool that I can create a listing address and target address(like TCPMon), and that can hold the message and let me edit the message and forward to the target address. Is there any tool like this for linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a middleware. You can use [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) which is freely available. You can just unzip and install the WSO2 ESB. You can send the request to WSO2 ESB and put a tcpmon in between client and ESB and again ESB and backend to view request and response.

Comment: Thank You.I got it sorted out. I wanted a tool like this because I am debugging  WSO2 ESB :)